# precise seek local video in adobe air

Tags: video, air

i want to make an application with adobe air for watching a video. the priority is to have a seek with a really fine granularity with seek(framneNumber). i'm usinf FLVPlayback object from FLVPlayebackAS3.swc:

```
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
```

first of all i'm not understand the precision of my seek: is it really in any frame or only in the I-frame of the GOF (Group Of Frame used in video compression - encoding).

then i'm looking for a clean way to seek in frame. i used this code:

```
    private function getFrameRate():int {
        if(playerFLV.metadataLoaded) return playerFLV.metadata.videoframerate;
        else return -1;
    }

    private function seek(frame:int):void {
        if(getFrameRate()>0)
            playerFLV.seek( frame / getFrameRate() );
    }
```

but sometimes it seems not to be precise enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the seek(time:Number) function expects a time int, and the its accuracy is limited to 3 decimals of milliseconds. a frame might fall just out of that with the calculation that you have above.

as a quick check are you sure the getFrameRate() is returning anything? shouldnt it be :

```
if(playerFLV.metadataLoaded) return playerFLV.metadata.framerate;
```

metadata.framerate will give you the flv frame rate, if you dont care about the audio, you can try using:

```
playerFLV.metadata.videodatarate
```

As for the two part question:

**RE- first of all i'm not understand the precision of my seek: is it really in any frame or only in the I-frame of the GOF (Group Of Frame used in video compression - encoding).**

***if the video is progressive download:***

the Seek will seek to a time then the playback component would display the first keyframe after that.

***if the video is streaming:***

The FMS would generate the required key frame at that exact time.

maybe another solution if you dont care about file size is to encode your flv with more keyframes, or if you do control the encoding of your videos and they are progressive then I would advise to add Que points on every frame you want to seek the video to.

Comment: i read video locally so i don't mind nor progressive download nor streaming server.. but i think it is treated like progressive download

Comment: it would be treated as progressive in that case. make sure you increase the amount of keyframes in your encoding in that case.

Comment: ok but, my question is: with a video in my local disk, there is any kind of way to achive a precise seek?

Comment: encode your video to contain more keyframes. then you can use the same function above and it would be valid. If you dont care about the size of a video it can be encoded to have 30 key frames/sec, in which case the above assumptions are correct.